# WordPress Mobile Detect as a body_class function

Tags: php, wordpress, function, wordpress-theming, responsive

I've been using the wondrous [mobile-detect](http://mobiledetect.net/) within my WordPress themes header for some time. It goes beyond CSS media queries and allows more flexibility with a responsive build.

However, I now want to add classes to the body tag depending on the device. So I have written a function, that should, in theory, work. However it is not, I get a desktop class regardless of device.

```
require_once( get_template_directory() . '/mobile-detect/Mobile_Detect.php' 
);
$detect = new Mobile_Detect;
$mobile = $detect->isMobile();
$tablet = $detect->isTablet();
function device_body_class ( $classes ) {
    if ( $mobile ) {
        $classes[] = 'mobile';
        if ( $tablet ) {
            $classes[] = 'tablet';
        } else {
            $classes[] = 'phone';
        }
    } else {
        $classes[] = 'desktop';
    }
    return $classes;
}
add_filter( 'body_class', 'device_body_class' );
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Big awkward hugs from Cornwall, UK.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try the following code :

```
function device_body_class ( $classes ) 
{
   $detect = new Mobile_Detect;
   $mobile = $detect->isMobile();
   $tablet = $detect->isTablet();
   if ( $mobile ) {
        $classes[] = 'mobile';
        if ( $tablet ) {
            $classes[] = 'tablet';
        } else {
            $classes[] = 'phone';
        }
    } else {
        $classes[] = 'desktop';
    }
    return $classes;
}
add_filter( 'body_class', 'device_body_class' );
```

Hope it works as expected.

Comment: I've just tested it and it works exactly as expected. Thank you so much. So the `$mobile` and `$tablet` variables needed to be inside the function, in retrospect that makes perfect sense. How come the `require_once` isn't needed?

Comment: Great it works for you, "require_once" is actually including the file where the class "Mobile_Detect" is written.